# Is it possible to solve this integral equation analytically?

Tags: integration, problem-solving

I have the equation

$$\frac {f(0)+\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}f'(t)dt} x=1$$

We can also write it as $$\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}f(t)dt=1$$

**How do we solve for $x$ so that this equation holds? Is it possible to do** **analytically for arbitrary $f(t)$?**

Comment: The second equation is the Laplace transform of a certain function.

Comment: is it, even if $x$ is Real rather than complex?

Comment: In practice, we can always find the solution: but it does not have a formula for arbitrary function $f$. The solution always related to the function. You also may find the solution for some classes of functions but not in general. See. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html

Comment: Thank you. But to be clear: if $x$ is restricted to a real variable, is $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt$ then still the Laplace transform of $f$?

Comment: @Programmer2134: Yes it is a Laplace transform with $s = x + j0$.  You can look up the Laplace transform of $f(t)$, possibly apply some Laplace transform theorems, substitute in $x $ for $s $, and then solve for $x $.  Not every function $f(t) $ will have a Laplace transform though.